# Icon for "More", like more results

Tags: mobile, icons

I need an intuitive icon which represents "more" ITEMS (or "more items like this") (or other "similar" items to this item). I have space constraints on the screen, so I can't exactly use a label.

Comment: Are you planning to use the icon at end of paragraphs of text, list of items, ... Different uses will require different icons.

Comment: hey emil, i've updated the question to better reflect my needs.

Answer (score 6):

You could combine the ellipsis and a right arrow as follows - where the arrow is similarly styled to the ellipsis - same height lines as dot diameter, same curvature, same colour, same spacing.

[image] [image]

larger version:

[image] [image]

[edit] After Philip's comment below, I added the downward versions just to compare and contrast...

Comment: This is a neat idea, but I'd go for it only if the content will be displayed in the direction where the arrow is pointing. in other words, it could work fine if the content area expands horizontally, but the metaphor would be lost if the content expands vertically (as the vertically aligned dots would no longer look like an ellipsis)

Comment: @Philip yep - agreed on that

Comment: They're not just very clear, but also very good looking!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the "icon" that's used a lot for this purpose is a simple ellipsis (...), probably as a contraction of "More..." or "Show more..."

Ex.:

[image]

Also popular are all sorts of arrows pointing in the direction where the additional content will be loaded.

Ex.:

[image]

[image]

Plus signs are also occasionally used.

Overall, it seems to depend largely on context. If the content is loaded below the button, an arrow pointing in that direction may be appropriate.

If the loaded content is "more of the same," an ellipsis may be a logical indicator, but if it's somthing that extends the currently visible information, but is not necessarily similar in nature, a plus may be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your input philip. To provide you with better context, in my app, I show the user an image. They can click an icon ('more'), to view similar images to this. '+' is a good candidate, but I'm not sure if it users will perceive it as 'more', specially if there are no labels.

Comment: @raunak, how about a triangle facing right. Users are familiar with the convention from picture sliders.

Comment: I already use that for loading the next image.

Comment: I would still suggest the Ellipsis (...), you can style it a little to make it look like a button. I remember reading a research paper on this topic but can't for the life of me recall the paper. IIRC most users simply preferred the word "more" and icons always took a bit of learning. Don't quote me as I can't find the article.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is my approach, ellipsis with some background color.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually use multiple offset versions of whatever you have more of, like this:

[image]

So for the example above, if you have a list of pages/documents, I would use something like this as an indicator of "more."